# Demora en proceso SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, tls

he tenido problemas al tratar de conectarme por protocolo HTTPS a aplicaciones de un servidor con IIS, las conexiones se tardan hasta un minuto y revisando los timings con las herramientas de desarrollo de IExplorer se tarda mucho tiempo en el proceso de SSL. Esto no sucede al conectarme por HTTP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente se tiene habilitado únicamente protocolo TLS1.2 ¿Cómo podría reducir estos tiempos?, Saludos

Comment: Tiene pinta de que algo no está funcionando. Esa petición acaba resolviendo bien? Quizá te sirva: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-ssl-related-issues-server-certificate

Comment: @nax Las peticiones si se resuelven bien, estuve haciendo unas pruebas y si en Internet Explorer se configura un proxy falso la petición se resuelve mucho más rápido, pero no logro saber el motivo.